# trying to save multiple select fields using update_options

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to display a list of all pages in a select field for a plugin I am developing. I want multiple pages to be able to be selected. I have been reading and reading, but still don't seem to get how this works. I am getting frustrated as this should be easy... :/

I can get the selected fields to echo out, but they don't seem to be saving, i.e. when page is reloaded the selections are gone.

the fields:

```
<select id="exclude_page_from_cookies" name="exclude_page_from_cookies[]" multiple="multiple">
            <?php

            $pages = get_pages();
            foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                $title = $page->post_title;
                $id    = $page->id;
                ?>

                <option id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $title ?>" <?php selected( $title ); ?> >
                    <?php echo $title;?>
                </option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
```

The save

```
if ( isset( $_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies'] ) ) {
            foreach( $_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies'] as $exclude_page ) {
                echo $exclude_page;
                update_option( 'exclude_page_from_cookies', $exclude_page ) ;
            }
        }
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if ( isset( $_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies'] ) ) {
    update_option('exclude_page_from_cookies',$_POST['exclude_page_from_cookies']);
}
```

Comment: what issue you are getting? Please explain

Comment: Just was a small difference in your code, rest was awesome

Comment: if (array_key_exists('exclude_pages_from_cookie', $_POST)) {
    update_option( 'exclude_pages_from_cookie', $_POST['exclude_pages_from_cookie']);
}

Answer (score 0):

he save (without any error checking, don't forget to validate your data):

```
if (array_key_exists('exclude_pages_from_cookie', $_POST)) {
    update_option( 'exclude_pages_from_cookie', $_POST['exclude_pages_from_cookie']);
}
```

I just noticed how old this post was. Oh well, responding anyway!

Thank You @vidhi for making me remember old code